# What does "mv file1 *.file1" do?

Tags: linux, bash, mv

When I issue the command

```
mv file1 *.file1
```

in the directory where file1 is located, it disappears. Where does it end up? I know `*` is a valid character in file names under Linux and that I should have escaped the `*` character to have the expected result like

```
mv file1 \*.file1
```

but if didn't escape it, where was it moved to?

Comment: It depends on what the glob `*.file1` matched.

Comment: What distro are you using? When I tried this on Ubuntu LTS it worked just as if I'd escaped the `*`.

Comment: No where I think `*` expand to directory content and no file could created. Does it report error? What did you observe ?

Comment: Distro is Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS and there was no error.

Comment: It moves the file as if the `*` has been escaped. Try `ls \*.file1`

Comment: Nope, it is not in the directory. `ls -la` as root doesn't list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result of `mv file1 *.file1` depends on what is matched by `*.file1`

- If `*.file1` matches nothing, then `file1` is renamed to `*.file1`
- If `*.file1` matches exactly one file, then `file1` is renamed to the name of the matched file, and the matched file is lost.
- If `*.file1` matches exactly one file, and that file is a directory, then `file1` is moved to the matched directory.
- If `*.file1` matches more than one files, and the last file matched is a directory, then `file1`, and all matched files (except this directory) will be moved to the directory.
- If `*.file1` matches more than one files, and the last file matched is NOT a directory, then `mv` will fail with an error.

See experiment below:

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="12.04.2 LTS, Precise Pangolin"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu precise (12.04.2 LTS)"
VERSION_ID="12.04"
$ ls
$ touch file1
$ ls
file1
$ mv file1 *.file1
$ ls
*.file1
$ touch file1
$ ls
file1  *.file1
$ mv file1 *.file1
$ ls
*.file1
$ touch 1.file1
$ touch file1
$ mv file1 *.file1
mv: target `*.file1' is not a directory
$ ls
1.file1  file1  *.file1
$ mkdir z.file1
$ mv file1 *.file1
$ ls z.file1/
1.file1  file1  *.file1
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Because I didn't get an error and the file is not there after the mv, it should be in the last matched directory as you suggest. How do I find out what that directory is?

Comment: "echo *.file1" will show you. Look at the end of the line returned

Comment: Thanks all of you for the help!

Comment: If there is exactly one file matching `*.file1`, `file1` will overwrite it.